# Sub-group worksheets / list objects

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to make groups of worksheets or list objects that can then be called when doing looping functions? So for example I have some lines of code that I want to run on a handful of tables that exist on a few worksheets in a much larger excel file. Currently I use code such as the following:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lstobj As ListObject

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lstobj In sht.ListObjects
        Blah blah blah
    Next lstobj
Next sht
```

However I only really need the code to loop through 5 or 6 tables that exist on 3 worksheets so looping through every single sheet and list object is a waste of time and ultimately will cause me problems when I don't want to run code on some objects. Can I make a sub-group of worksheets and a sub-group of tables that I can run the code on or will I have to call each one individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have specified/named objects, you can assign them in an array and loop through them.

Here's an example of doing so with an Excel spreadsheet with 4 sheets, but the loop only goes through 3 of them (1, 2 and 4).

```
Dim worksheets(2) As Excel.Worksheet
Set worksheets(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set worksheets(1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set worksheets(2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)

Dim worksheetVar As Variant ' Excel.Worksheet
For Each worksheetVar In worksheets
    MsgBox worksheetVar.Name

    If worksheetVar.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then  
        MsgBox "Has List Objects"
    End If
Next
```